# Bridging header conversion in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, bridging-header

How I can convert this Objective-C format into Swift? I already create a bridging header called `Bridging-Header.h`.

I already import this library header into bridging header.

```
#import "DraggableView.h"
#import "DraggableViewBackground.h"
#import "OverlayView.h"
```

Then I want to convert this Objective-C thing into swift.

```
DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:draggableBackground];
```

What I already done so far, I call the object `DraggableViewBackground` from `DraggableViewBackground.h` in my `ViewController.swift`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var instanceOfDraggableViewBackground: DraggableViewBackground = DraggableViewBackground()

    }
}
```

Reference library: https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Replace with your `frame`

```
var draggable = DraggableViewBackground(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
self.view.addSubview(draggable)
```